# parsear un archivo de texto con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsear, pipe

Soy nuevo en la plataforma y en el mundo de python.

Me gustaria poder hacer un pequeño script en el cual yo le doy un archivo.txt, el cual contiene una cadena de texto separada por | , y por cada | que hay se haga un salto de linea (entiendo que seria un \n), pero no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo. no se si seria con un for, y en caso de ser asi que sentencia usar para decirle que por cada | que encuentre realice un salto de linea.

a modo de ejemplo:

```
input: 

textouno|textodos|textotres
```

```
output:

textouno
textodos
textotres
```

Adjunto codigo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
from io import open
path = 'C:/Users/mark/Desktop/pipelines.txt'
archivo = open(path,'r')

# (aqui entiendo que deberia venir la parte del parseo)

print (archivo.read())
archivo.close()
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, realmente es muy sencillo de hacerlo, pero por favor primero intenta hacer algo por tu cuenta. Por ejemplo puedes empezar mirando en Internet como leer un archivo en python y a partir de ahí ir sacando pequeñas soluciones. Si llegas a un momento que ves que te atascas entonces publica una pregunta y por favor incluye la parte de código ya que a otros nos ayudan mucho para poder darte una mejor solución

Comment: Hola, olvide adjuntar el codigo en la primera pregunta.
Codigo:

from io import open
path = 'C:/Users/mark/Desktop/pipelines.txt'

archivo = open(path,'r')
#aqui entiendo que deberia venir la parte del parseo 
print (archivo.read())
archivo.close()

Comment: La parte del parseo iría después de leer el fichero, no antes porque si no todavía no tienes datos. La idea es `contenido = archivo.read()` para leer todo el contenido del archivo a una variable, y después puedes usar `contenido.split("|")`, para trocear esa cadena por los `"|"`. El resultado es una lista de cadenas. Basta iterar por esa lista e imprimir cada elemento. El `print()` ya te añade un salto de línea automáticamente.

Comment: muchas gracias abulafia, segui tus consejos y logre mi cometido.

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Para reemplazar caracteres en una cadena usa replace.

Ej:

```
a = 'linea uno|linea dos|linea tres|'
b = a.replace('|','\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

El tema se podría resolver con sólo 2 líneas:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read().replace('|', '\n'))
```

En realidad, no necesitas el **import**. Por otra parte, al trabajar con ficheros, es conveniente utilizar un contexto (**with**) que hace las funciones de un bloque **try** y cerrará el fichero automáticamente al finalizar.

Hemos asignado un alias al fichero (**as f**) para poder referenciarlo. Leemos su contenido (**f.read()**), reemplazamos **|** por **\n** (**.replace('|', '\n')**) y finalmente lo imprimimos (**print(...)**).